# How can I ensure that my external monitor will show my programs by default?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I use a laptop (lenovo T530) with a base station connecting to external monitor and keyboard, using Windows 7

[image: System Information]

[image: Screen Resolution Settings]

## Expected Behavior

When I plug my laptop into the base station, everything currently displaying on my laptop monitor (while it was unplugged) should move to the external monitor which sits to the left side (with same resolution). The laptop screen should change to display an empty background. When opening a new program, the window should appear first on the primary display. If I really want, I can drag it to the secondary display (on the laptop screen).

## Actual Behavior

The programs stay on the laptop monitor (now the secondary display), but the desktop icons, taskbar, and start button are all moved to the external monitor (which is now primary display).

## Workarounds

1. Drag & Drop every... single... friggin... window to the primary display (the monitor plugged into the base station)... but if I open a new program, it opens on the laptop rather than the primary display, so it is unpredictable which monitor the program will open first with.
2. Disable the laptop monitor and use one monitor only... sigh

## My Reaction

Cut to... every time this happens my brain says "how DARE you put my program on the secondary display. I NEED THAT OVER HERE!... ARRRGG"

## Possibilities

I use this laptop to plug into different base stations depending on what office I'm in. In one scenario the monitor has larger resolution and is to the right side. In another, the monitor is the same resolution and is to the left side. Maybe this is messing it up somehow. Since I've experienced the behavior listed under "Expected Behavior" before, so I know it's possible. Suprisingly, though, Windows is smart enough to know which resolution and side to use depending on what place I'm at.